# EditText typed value not showing at some devices

Tags: android

I have a really strange problem.
The typed values are not showing at the EditText but only on some devices. on other devices it is working ok.

here is the EditText XML:

```
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/admin_Password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/frame1"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Enter Password"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>
```

I have tried with and without the below but it is still not working.

```
             android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

I have a problem that the soft keyboard was not shown up at some devices so i have the following code to get it shown up:

```
        InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        im.showSoftInput(enteredAdminPassword, 0);
```

and it cause the keyboard to show up but when typing, nothing is shown at the EditText.

just for more information, this is the only EditText at the layout and when it shown up, the "Enter Password" is selected.

I am really need and help with this case.

thanks

Comment: Are all this lines needed? android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:focusable="true"

Comment: basically yes. anyway i have tried also without them and the problem was not solved. Please note, it is happened only on some devices. e.g. on my Xiomi it is working ok, but on Sumsong A8 it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is funny, but issue was solved by adding the following:

```
                android:inputType="textPassword"
```

i have no explanation and i will be more than happy to have explanation.